# How to create percent stacked shape with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

is there a way that I could do Percent stacked plot with `ggplot2` `geom_rect()` layer? I have coordinates, so I create a shape, I also have my separation variable `t`, now I would like to fill the shape based on the occurrence of `t`. In other words, I would like to do Percent stacked barchart but instead of a barchart a custom shape (in my case, simple rectangles). I've been experimenting a lot with `position="fill"`, `stat="identity"` and their varieties but without any success. I wonder if it possible and if so, how could I achieve it?

```
df <- structure(list(x1 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3), x2 = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), y1 = c(3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), y2 = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), t = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
    geom_rect(data=d, mapping=aes(xmin=x1, xmax=x2, ymin=y1, ymax=y2, fill = t))
```

expected result
[image]

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working code for the desired plot, it took some coding using `dplyr`, but it worked.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

df1<-df %>%
  group_by(x1,y1,x2,y2,t) %>%
  count() %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(x1,y1) %>%
  mutate(perc = n / sum(n),
         percLabel = paste(100 * perc,"%",sep = " "),
         transf = abs(x2-x1) * perc,
         newx1 = ifelse(t == "a", x1,x2-transf),
         newx2 = ifelse(t == "a", x1+transf,x2)) 


ggplot(df1,aes(xmin = newx1, 
               xmax = newx2, 
               ymin = y1, 
               ymax = y2, 
               fill = t)) + 
  geom_rect(col = "black") + 
  geom_text(aes(x = newx1 + ((newx2 - newx1)/2), 
                              y = y1 + ((y2 - y1)/2), 
                              label = percLabel)) + 
  labs(x="X",y="Y")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!.. :) I would like to buy you a beer! Would you give me your PayPal? I am serious!

Comment: Haha, it is ok (although, I would like a beer right now). This is how SO work: people helping other people. I am glad it worked.

Comment: Alright then! :) Thank you once again! All the best,